# C# if else user input handling issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-input

I'm building a simple console based monster battling game for training purposes.

I've created a while loop which is almost where I need it to be but when the user enters an incorrect choice, the final "incorrect input" type message just loops infinitely on the screen.

Could somebody suggest a fix please?

Or, should I use a try, catch exception handler instead (I'm not very good at those yet).

Thank you,

code follows:

P.S The variable boolean acceptInput is initialized at the top of the class which is not included in this code segment.

```
 while (!acceptInput)
                    {
                    if (playerChoice == "a" || playerChoice == "h")
                    {
                        if (playerChoice == "a")
                        {
                            player.PlayerAttack();
                            if (random.NextDouble() > .9)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You missed!");
                                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
                                Console.ReadLine();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("It's a hit!");
                                monster.MonsterDecreaseHealth(player.AttackPower);
                                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
                                Console.ReadLine();
                            }
                            acceptInput = true;
                        }
                        else if (playerChoice == "h")
                        {
                            player.PlayerHeal();
                            acceptInput = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid choice, please enter either A or H");
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: you need to include how you get the value for `playerChoice`.

Comment: You're not changing the loop condition on invalid input, so why would anything change? you need to get `playerChoice` from the player *inside* the loop, otherwise it will never change.

Comment: Why is your  `while (!acceptInput)` inverted why not just `while (acceptInput)` seem confusing. in English that would read like `while **not** accepting input do everything in here in a repeatedly`

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly. Remark like  "The variable boolean acceptInput ... is not included in this code segment." definitely shows that the sample is not complete (and it is definitely not minimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Pintang said above, it's because the user is not given an opportunity to reset the value of the playerChoice variable. At the beginning of the while loop, you need to allow the playerChoice variable to be reset to a new input. There is currently no method for the user to update the value of playerChoice, so if the first instance of the condition is evaluated to false, there will be an infinite loop. I would do something like this

```
while (!acceptInput)
{
    playerChoice = GetUserInput(); // GetUserInput() return user input string

    if (playerChoice.Equals("a"))
    {
        player.PlayerAttack();

        if (Random.NextDouble() > 0.9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Missed!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to Continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a hit!");
            monster.MonsterDecreaseHealth(player.AttackPower);
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to Continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        acceptInput = true;
    }

    else if (playerChoice.Equals("h"))
    {
        player.PlayerHeal();

        acceptInput = true;
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid choice, please enter either A or H");
    }
}
```

Comment: What [@edm2282](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8309428/edm2282) meant to say is, if you don't set `playerChoice` to be read again, your program will loop forever because it will always have the same value. Place `playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();` after your "That is not a valid choice" message.